# MySQL  - приемы упрощения множественных запросов

Tags: php, mysql

1. Создаю новую запись в базе
2. Вытаскиваю последний id
3. Делаю действия в php
4. Обновляю созданную запись по id

или

1. Проверяю есть ли email в базе
2. Если нет создаю новую запись
3. Вытаскиваю созданный id
4. Если есть вытаскиваю id и обновляю запись

или

1. Проверяю есть ли в базе запись
2. Если запись есть узнаю ее id
3. Узнаю количество записей в базе
4. Обновляю запись по id

Как видите везде для 1 действия выполняется 4 запроса к базе, очень надоел такой подход

Можно как то упростить sql запросы (допустим обьеденив?)

Как вы делаете авторизацию регистрацию и т.д.?

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от задачи: можно ли то, что вы делаете на стороне PHP, реализовать целиком в MySQL — с помощью [переменных](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html), выполнения нескольких запросов подряд, условных операторов и т.п.

Для таблиц типа InnoDB можно использовать [транзакции](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/innodb-transaction-model.html) — изолированные последовательности действий, внутри которых вы можете быть уверены, что никто не вставит ещё одну запись, и не собъёт данные записей, с которыми вы работаете.

Особенно для второго вашего примера может помочь [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Позволяет сразу вставлять, или укзаать, что и как обновлять, если запись с таким id уже существует.

Чтобы узнать, как «другие» делают регистрацию/авторизацию, полезно покопаться в коде популярных фреймворков и CMS. Разберитесь, как это сделано в Joomla и WordPress, например.

Answer (score 1):

[ООП. !!!Пользуйтесь классами !!!](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

**UPD^**

Использование объектно-реляционного отображения (ORM) дает ряд преимуществ. 
Все, что можно сделать в ORM , можно сделать вручную, но с большими усилиями и более высокими требованиями к уровню разработчика.

ORM отлично подходит для "ленивой загрузки". Это означает, что получение значений возможно тогда, когда они нужны. Но нужно быть аккуратным, потому что можно создать много маленьких запросов, которые понизят производительность.

ORM может также объединять ваши запросы в транзакции, которые выполняются существенно быстрее, чем индивидуальные запросы к базе данных.

Для PHP можно использовать `Doctrine`.

Comment: Как там? "Не забывай, когда ты пользуешься классами, классы пользуются тобой"? Как классы могут сократить количество запросов?

Comment: @alexlz,  а что,не догадываетесь ?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd Нет, не догадываюсь. Для меня это звучит как "Какие лампы, какие транзисторы, рация -- на бронепоезде!"

Comment: @alexlz, ну я свой вариант предложил просто, буду рад почитать и ваш вариант. Кстати, С НГ!

Comment: @Vfvtnjd И Вас с Новым Годом! Просто для варианта хотелось бы вопрос пояснее. А ORM к количеству запросов к mysql-серверу относится как-то перепендикулярно. Организация обработки -- может быть, но это уже другая материя.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, важно правильно спроектировать всю базу данных. Кроме этого, надо хорошенько обдумать логическую цепочку действий. Понимаю, что ваши примеры образные, но если их разобрать, то обнаруживаем много лишних телодвижений.

Пример номер раз: зачем создавать запись, для того, чтоб её сразу же апдейтить? Кроме того, для второго пункта запрос не нужен. Чтоб получить id только что вставленной записи, достаточно использовать функцию [last_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php) или [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php) (для PHP 5.5.+), или для PDO - [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Пример второй: Проверять наличие записи в таблице и, в зависимости от результата, создавать новую или апдейтить существующую, можно одним запросом, используя конструкцию [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

В третьем примере - ситуация аналогичная. Только получить кол-во записей надо будет делать отдельным запросом.

Comment: Из жизни: для примера номер раз как-то нужно было считать по хитрому алгоритму ключ, типа короткой ссылки, из id пользователя, и прописывать его в другую ячейку.

Comment: @sergiks, дело ясное, что ситуации бывают не стандартные, только я разбирал пример, который описал ТС.

Comment: @deonis: попытался проинтуичить, какие там "действия в php" могут выполняться со свежесозданной записью из первого примера ТС.